# Connecting to Oracle with JDBC causes queries to return zero rows.

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

So I have been playing around with querying databases using the standard

```
Statement s = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = s.executQuery(queryString);
ResultSetMetadata rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

while(rs.next)){
   String code = "";
   String value = "";

   for(int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++){
      Object obj = rs.getObject(i);
      if(i == 1){
          code = obj.toString():
      }
      else{
          label = obj.toString();
      }
   }
   //Store code and labels in map
}

...go on to close statement and move on.
```

I am trying to select two columns from a table in each instance.

For the most part this works well. When working with MySql & Microsoft Sql databases I get a result set full of data in the table. However when I try to do this with an Oracle database I get an empty result set.

I have tested my query string in the SQL Developer application and it works fine, returns my data. But the result set doesnt contain anything. The resultSet metadata says that it has two columns though. Is there anything I need to do when interacting with an Oracle Database that is different from the other two? Thanks.

Comment: well you have to "turn on" the pointer: while(rs.next()){}

Comment: Can you paste the code that you using while interacting with oracle ??

Comment: well of course I am using rs.next(), but I guess I should have included that :) see latest edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your query works when you run it against the Oracle database, and you know the code works since you've run it against MySQL, then some other things to try are:

1.) Make sure your JDBC connection URL is correct.  Are you sure you are connecting to the database that you intend to?  (i.e. - the one that would return the rows you expect?)

2.) Take into account credentials.  Make sure you are using the same credentials through JDBC that you are when connecting to Oracle directly.

3.) Make sure both connections are being made from the same machine and with the same environment.  Oracle drivers rely on environment variables to find a file (I believe it is called tnsnames.ora, or something like that) that contains the alias & connection info. Getting different versions of that file could point you to different Oracle instances.

4.) Try manually specifying your schema name in the query. So instead of `select * from my_table` use `select * from my_schema.my_table`. Sometimes Oracle clients will configure their sessions to have default schemas set up in their preferences.

5.) If your are attempting to select data that you've inserted with your Oracle client, make sure you've committed the transaction in your Oracle client so that the data is visible to other sessions.

One last debugging tool to use is to try connecting via the Squirrel DB client.  Squirrel is a 100% pure java SQL client that connects to any DB using JDBC. It would be a good test to make sure your JDBC Driver, Connection URL, etc. are all valid.

Comment: I am sure my credentials are right, I have been examining them a lot, I also know that my connection string is right because I use it to connect to the database and look at table names. One interesting thing I noticed though is that my query works in SQL developer with or without an ending ";" However, my queryString doesnt return data without the ";" and will through a SQL command not properly ended exception if I do include it...

Comment: @decal I would download the Squirrel SQL client and try connecting from that.  It is a 100% pure java SQL client that connects to any DB using JDBC.  It would be a good test to make sure your JDBC Driver, Connection URL, etc. are all valid.

Comment: @decal When you download the Squirrel client, you will have to point it at your JDBC driver and configure it like you would a JDBC connection.  Also, when you are testing against Oracle using Java JDBC vs. the Oracle DB Client, are you making both of those connections from the same machine?  I know Oracle drivers rely on env variables to find a file (I believe it is called tnsnames.ora, or something like that) that contains the alias & connection info.  Getting different versions of that file could point you to different Oracle instances...

Comment: I am trying to make a connection from the same machine that I have sql developer opened on.

Comment: @decal You may also try manually specifying your schema name in your query.  So instead of `select * from my_table` use `select * from my_schema.my_table`.  Sometimes Oracle clients will configure their sessions have default schemas set up in their preferences.

Comment: So this was kind of weird, but I think nothing was being returned because nothing was there... After trying to connect from squirrel, it also showed that there were no records in my table. Just realized SQL Developer needs to commit after running these, not used to oracle so I did not know that. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Ok, I will update my answer with all of the things we tried to try and help the next guy.  :)

Answer (score -1):

The database table has records but the JDBC client can't retrieve the records. Means the JDBC client doesn't have the select privileges. Please run the below query on command line:

```
grant  all on emp to hr;
```